# How to add policy to access secret with lambda function AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to give access permission of secret manager to my lambda function in SAM template but it is giving me error that policy statement is malformed.

```
     Policies:
      - Statement:
      - Sid: AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy
        Effect: Allow
        Action: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
        Resource: <arn >
```

Can some one let me know the correct way of adding policy to my lambda function.
I am using SAM template (Type: AWS::Serverless::Function)

Answer (score 5):

This policy only accepts ARN of a secret, so secret name will not work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#secrets-manager-get-secret-value-policy

Below works for me.

```
Resources:  
MyFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  CodeUri: MyProject/
  Handler: app
  Policies:
    - AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy:
        SecretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:####'
```

or passing it as a parameter

```
    - AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy:
        SecretArn: !Ref RdsSecretArn
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [SAM Policy Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-templates.html) where one of them is [AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#secrets-manager-get-secret-value-policy) you can use them directly in the definition.

Or if you wanna manage the policies yourself.

```
    QueryFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
        Handler: lambda_handler.lambda
        Policies:
            - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
            - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
            - SSMParameterReadPolicy:
                ParameterName: parameter_name
            - Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                    - dynamodb:*
                Resource: 'resource_arn'
        Runtime: python3.7
```

Comment: I have to define policy for secret manager access not for SSM parameter.

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal there is a policy for that as well in the templates, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Policies:
      - Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
            Resource: <arn >
```

Answer (score 0):

This policy on the lambda works for me (YAML)

```
Policies:
  - AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy:
      SecretArn:
        Ref: THE_NAME_YOU_GAVE_YOUR_SECRET_RESOURCE
```